# How to query a specific shard for a document

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-java-api

I can use the [preference](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-preference.html) to query ES shard #2 for tweet document with id `1` with URL like this:

```
GET twitter/tweet/1/_search?preference=_shards:2
```

How can I do this with Java API?

EDIT
This:

```
GET /bookshop/book/_search?preference=_shards:0
```

lists the document while the both below returns NPE:

```
GET /bookshop/book/id1?preference=_shards:0 //NPE
```

and

```
GetResponse getResponse =  client()
            .prepareGet(BOOK_INDEX_NAME, BOOK_TYPE_NAME, "id1")
            .setPreference("_shards:0")
            .execute().actionGet();

    System.out.print(getResponse.getSource()); //HERE IS WHERE I GET THE NPE
```

**EDIT 2:**

Why then if I have only two shards for this index for

```
 GET /bookshop/book/id1?preference=_shards:0
```

I get NPE and for

```
> GET /bookshop/book/id1?preference=_shards:1
```

I get "found:false":

```
{
   "_index": "bookshop",
   "_type": "book",
   "_id": "id1",
   "found": false
}
```

and

```
GET /bookshop/book/_search?preference=_shards:0
```

gets the actual document with `id1` and the complete `_source`?

```
{
   "took": 2,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 1,
      "successful": 1,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 1,
      "max_score": 1,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "bookshop",
            "_type": "book",
            "_id": "id1",
            "_score": 1,
            "_routing": "route1",
            "_source": {
               "title": "Clean COde",
               "author": "John Smith"
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

**EDIT3:**
For:

```
GET /bookshop/book/id1?preference=_shards:0
```

I get the following responce

```
{
   "error": {
      "root_cause": [
         {
            "type": "remote_transport_exception",
            "reason": "[master-1][127.0.0.1:9304][indices:data/read/get[s]]"
         }
      ],
      "type": "null_pointer_exception",
      "reason": null
   },
   "status": 500
}
```

Comment: Are you sure about your URL? Are you referencing a single doc (with id=1) or are you willing to run a search (i.e. `/_search`)? You cannot do both.

Comment: I'd like to search a single shard for a `tweet` document with a given id. Is it doable?

Comment: You need to remove the `_search` endpoint. I've modified my answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it like this using the `setPreference()` call:

```
response = client()
    .prepareGet("twitter", "tweet", "1")
    .setRouting("route1")
    .setPreference("_shards:2")
    .execute().actionGet();
```

Comment: Thank you this is what I was looking for :) Upvoted and accepted

Comment: hmm with `GET /twitter/tweet/_search?preference=_shards:2` I get the documen,t but when I try to run `response.getSource()`. I get NPE. What can be the problem?

Comment: You're doing a search instead of getting the document? Update your question with the exact Java code you're using

Comment: But isn't it that if I search for a doc and the search responses with the doc I am after so the `get` on the `id` field of that doc should also bring me the same document?

Comment: You're mixing two different APIs: 1) Search API `/twitter/tweet/_search` will return a list of matching hits (possibly containing your document with id=1) and 2) Get API `/twitter/tweet/1` returning ONLY your document with id=1

Comment: If you get an NPE, it might be because your document doesn't live on the specified shard.

Comment: Why then if I have only two shards for this index for `GET /bookshop/book/id1?preference=_shards:0` I get NPE and for `GET /bookshop/book/id1?preference=_shards:1` I get "found:false" and `GET /bookshop/book/_search?preference=_shards:0` gets the actual document?

Comment: What is the pure JSON response for `GET /bookshop/book/id1?preference=_shards:0` ?

Comment: I have placed it in EDIT 3.

Comment: Thanks, can you also add the relevant part of the ES logs which show that NPE?

Comment: I use esvm for my testing case. Where can I find log file? Or do you mean the Java API log?

Comment: I have enriched the ansewer to show the propper result of `GET /bookshop/book/_search?preference=_shards:0`
Can the routing be the case here?

Comment: You probably need to add `setRouting("route1")` to your call indeed

Comment: And again we have tackled the problem :) Thank you !